# I need to set intervals inside the request of the body

Tags: python, python-requests, confluent-cloud

I have this python telemetry scraper from Confluent:

```
import os
import time
import json
import urllib3
import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def send_telemetry_request(username, password):
    url = "https://api.telemetry.confluent.cloud/v2/metrics/cloud/query"

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    auth = (username, password)

    body = {
        "aggregations": [{"metric": "io.confluent.kafka.server/request_count"}],
        "filter": {
            "op": "OR",
            "filters": [{"field": "resource.kafka.id", "op": "EQ", "value": "$CLUSTER"}]
        },
        "granularity": "PT1M",
        "intervals": [f"{start_time_iso}/{end_time_iso}"],
        "limit": 1000
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, auth=auth, json=body)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Request successful!")
            return response.json()  # Return the JSON content if the status code is 200
            # You can process the response content here if needed
        else:
            print(f"Request failed with status code: {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I need to update "intervals" in the body so it just gets latest data every minute.

If define intervals in the body:
        `"intervals": ["2024-01-29T12:29:00-06:00/2024-01-29T13:29:00-06:00"],`
It works fine